# Quando "QU" e "GU" são dígrafos, o "U" pode ser considerado para formar um tritongo?

Tags: fonologia

A dúvida surgiu na análise fonológica da seguinte palavra: **"sequoia"**

É de conhecimento que **"gu"** e **"qu"** são dígrafos apenas quando seguidos de **"e"** ou **"i"**

Ex: queda, queijo, guerra

No caso de **"sequoia"**, **"qu"** é seguido de **"o"**, logo **"u"**  é um fonema, logo uma semivogal. Neste caso, ela pode ser considerada para formar o tritongo na forma **Semivogal + Vogal + Semivogal** (divisão silábica: se-q**UOI**-a).

*Agora a questão é*: nos casos em que **"qu"** e **"gu"** são dígrafos, são duas letras que formam um único fonema, o que torna o **"u"** sozinho fonologicamente nada. Ele não é um fonema em si, só tem um forma fonética se junto do **"q"** ou **"g"**. Então se esse **"u"** for seguido sucessivamente de uma vogal e uma semivogal, essa sequência **"u" + vogal + semivogal** pode ser considerada um tritongo ou não?

Ex: queijo

- divisão silábica: quei-jo
- **qu** => dígrafo
- **uei** = seria tritongo ou não?

Comment: É preferível tratar como dois ditongos [seˈkwɔ.jɐ].

Answer (score 1):

Para mim, você já respondeu.  En "quei", "u" não é vogal, então so há ditongo.  Seria tritongo "qüei", usando a antiga grafia.  Buscando no Google, encontrei "Qüei" come nome próprio.

Comment: Então, essa era minha dúvida: se analisar o "u" desconsiderando o dígrafo, a gente pode achar direto que é um tritongo. A picuinha que estou fazendo é porque vou prestar concurso público, então quero ficar atento aos detalhes.

Comment: Não confie em mim!